# I thought Dapper could merge multiple queries like this

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

I'm using the Dapper micro ORM. I thought it could handle enumerables like this:

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM Events WHERE TimestampTicks <= @TimestampTicks AND TelemetryId = @TelemetryId ORDER BY TimestampTicks DESC LIMIT 1";
var events = _connection.Query<ReplayEvent>(sql, telemetryIds.Select(ti => new { TimestampTicks = startTime.Ticks, TelemetryId = ti }));
```

Alas it gives a worthless error. Does the Query method not have a way to merge multiple results? What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think it's legal for the second argument to `Query` to be a sequence?  Usually you pass in an an anonymous type containing your arguments, not an enumerable.  (looking at your query, I'm not at all sure what you're even hoping it will do)

Comment: The "LIMIT 1" is supposed to imply that I expect one result for each id in the telemetryIds collection.

Comment: Dapper will not write that query for you. (dapper does not modify your query -- it doesn't parse it and manipulate it)  You'll have to write it yourself using an `in` clause.

Comment: I wasn't expecting Dapper to change the query. I was expecting it to execute that query multiple times (possibly in parallel) and merge the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could do this using a subquery and using the build in 'List Support' referenced on the [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) page:

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM Events e WHERE TimestampTicks = 
    (SELECT MAX(TimestampTicks) FROM Events WHERE TimestampTicks <=@TimestampTicks AND TelemetryId = e.TelemetryId ) 
    AND e.TelemetryId IN @TelemetryIds;"
var events = _connection.Query<ReplayEvent>(sql, new {TelemtryIds = telemetryIds, TimestampTicks = startTime.Ticks});
```

Comment: Will this fail if TimestampTicks is not unique? In other words, do I need to join the e.Id to Events.Id and does the MAX operator return the ID for the correct row?

Comment: What happened when you tried running it against your db @Brannon? You could try to change the subquery to `SELECT Id .... ORDER BY TimestampTicks DESC LIMIT 1` and see if that gets you what you need.

Comment: I ended up using my original plan inside a Parallel.For with cloned connections for each thread. However, I think this approach is workable if you don't need the extra speed of the parallel queries.